# self hosted dropbox-like solution for windows

Tags: file-sharing

Are you guys aweare of a software that works like dropbox for windows? (mobile clients, other OSes are a plus)

Track file changes, Synchronization conflicts resolution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions here - that your issues with dropbox is security,

Assuming you just need a client, there's a lot of options available - [wuala](http://www.wuala.com/), [sugarsyn](https://www.sugarsync.com/)c and [spideroak](https://spideroak.com/) seem popular - spideroak is probably the most secure of the lot.

If you want to host your own, you'll need to wait a while -[aerofs](http://www.aerofs.com/) and [ifolder](http://www.kablink.org/ifolder) are the most mature seeming of the windows options Aerofs dosen't need a server, while ifolder does. I'm personally keeping an eye on [syncany](http://www.syncany.org/) and [sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/) - they're not mature yet, but they seem to be the closest to a 'dropbox like' experience - sadly in both cases, windows clients are 'any time soon' rather than available.

Answer (score 0):

I have the PogoPlug pro device that I have attached to a 2TB drive, but they also have software you can install on your PC and do the same thing...

http://software.pogoplug.com/